# Isomorphisms betweenVerma modules over a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory

Fix a finite dimensional, semisimple Lie algebra $L$ and denote the Verma $L$-modules by $V(\lambda ')$ where $\lambda '$ are corresponding weights.

Assume that there is an isomorphism between two Verma modules $V(\mu)$ and $V(\lambda)$, then by the Harish-Chandra theorem we may conclude that $\mu$ is in the orbit of $\lambda$ under the Weyl group actions.

But I really want to know if we be able to prove this without the Harish-Chandra theorem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124138/isomorphisms-between-verma-modules-over-a-lie-algebra